# Defining square root by series, and showing properties.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm triyng to define the root of a complex number near $1$ using the Taylor's series for $\sqrt{1+x}$, but I'm having some problems.

Let $x\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|x|<1$. Let $$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k(2k)!}{(1-2k)(k!)^24^k}x^k.$$By the root test, $y$ is well-defined. How could I show that $y^2=1+x$? I tried the following:

For every $k\in\left\{0,1,2,\ldots\right\}$, let $$a_k=\dfrac{(-1)^k(2k)!}{(1-2k)(k!)^24^k}.$$ We can show by induction that $a_0=1$ and for every $k\geq 1$,
$$a_k=\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-(k-1)\right).$$ Since the series that defines $y$ converges absolutely in $\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1|<1\right\}$, then
$$y^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^na_k a_{n-k}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\dfrac{(2k)!(2(n-k))!}{(1-2k)(1-2(n-k))(k!)^2(n-k)!^2}x^n$$

We can calculate $\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}$ for small $n$ (I calculated till $n=5$), and get $$y^2=1+x+0x^2+0x^3+0x^4+0x^5+\cdots.$$ I'm having a lot of trouble trying to show that $\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}=0$ for every $n\geq 2$.

(I know we can define roots in other ways, but I really want to see that this one works fine)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take the function $y=y(x)$. Show that $(1+x)y'(x)=\frac{1}{2}y(x)$.

Then $y^2=yy=2(1+x)y'y=(1+x)(y^2)'$

So $z:=y^2$ satisfies $(1+x)z'=z$. Solve for $z$.

Use that $y(0)=z(0)=1$.